# Datatable v3 Column Header Not Aligned with Column Data with XY Scrolling

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, datatables

I'm using bootstrap v3 for my project and I applied a datatable in it..I'm using the xy scroll for my table since it has a lot of entries...the problem is, the column header and column data of my table is not properly aligned..I think the problem occurs in the bootstrap.css coz when I tried to remove it to my html file the table seems to work properly..I did a tracing in bootstrap.css coz there might be classes that affects the table but all I see is this code;

```
    *,
    *:before,
    *:after {
       -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
       -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
       box-sizing: border-box;
     }
```

but the problem is, when I removed that script my layout ended up in mess..any idea what should be done with this?..please...

here's my datatable script;

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#example').dataTable( {
                "sScrollY": 200,
                "sScrollX": "100%",

            } );
        } );
```

Comment: did you manage to find a solution for the problem?